# Adding Products CSV data to database that has the entity tables: Products and Categories, based on the CategoryName column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a CMS system where a user can add `Category objects`, then the user can click on a created category and add `Product objects` to it.

I am now developing a `CSV data import form` which should allow users to do the same thing but with a single CSV file upload.

The CSV file data (shaded grey) is a list of products. Note - category name column for each product:

[image: CSV_Data.png]

This is the class for Product and Category:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool ShowOnIndex { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship that I currently have between Categories and Products is `One-to-Many`; a Category has many Products, a Product has only one Category. The CategoryId is the foreign key in the Products table in the SQL Server.

I have a form in my ASP.NET MVC application which allows a user to upload a CSV file which is then uploaded and saved into the AppData folder. The Post request for the CSV upload goes to the code below. It is here where I need to split the data from the CSV file to be able to import products correctly into my database:

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> CSVToList(HttpPostedFileBase CSVFile)
        {

            if (CSVFile == null || CSVFile.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No file has been selected for upload or the file is empty.");
            }

            // saves the file into a directory in the App_Data folder
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(CSVFile.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), fileName);
            CSVFile.SaveAs(path);

            CSVProducts = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                          let columns = line.Split(',')
                          select new Product
                          {
                              Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                              Barcode = columns[13],
                              Name = columns[1],
                              CategoryName = columns[9],
                              Description = columns[2],
                              Price = int.Parse(columns[4])
                          };


            return CSVProducts;
        }
```

However, the LINQ query above gets a list of products and I need to be able to store these into my database in accordance with the two entities: Categories and Products. Can someone suggest a way to do this. I am new to LINQ.

I want to be able to extract all of the unique Category names into a list and add these to the Categories table in the database, and then be able to add each product in accordance to the associated Category Name. I assume the Categories are supposed to be imported first - I have no data file for categories. Usually the user would manually write a category name and upload an image manually to create a category in my current CMS.

Comment: there are numerous CSV parsing libraries which will do a better job of things than `string.split`.  CSVHelper for instance

Comment: Or the built-in [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Creates Product objects from array of records
// At present, images are assumed void
// When CSV data contains images, then this code will need changing slightly.

        var CSVProducts = from line in records
                          let columns = line.Split(',')
                          select new Product
                          {
                              Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                              Barcode = columns[13],
                              Name = columns[1],
                              CategoryName = CapitaliseWords(columns[9]),
                              Description = columns[2],
                              Price = decimal.Parse(columns[4])
                          };

        ProductsList = CSVProducts.ToList();

        var CSVCategories = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
                           .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ',' })[9])
                           .Where(category => category.Length > 0)
                           .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                           .Select(s => new Category { Name = CapitaliseWords(s) });

            CategoriesList = CSVCategories.ToList();
```